# TCP Server Resetting AcceptSocket.ReceiveAsync operation on a SocketAsyncEventArgs instance

Tags: c#, server, tcp

I currently have a TCP Server implemented using C# SAEA.  What I would like to do is forward a message between 2 TCP Clients connected to the server (**Client 1** and **Client 2**).

- The Server uses **receiveSendEventArgs.AcceptSocket.ReceiveAsync** and
  **receiveSendEventArgs.AcceptSocket.SendAsync** commands to send and
  receive information from each of the connected clients with no
  problem.
- The Server is in **receiveSendEventArgs.AcceptSocket.ReceiveAsync** operation for both **Client 1** and **Client 2**.
- **Client 1** sends one Message and the the Server Accepts the message. The Server sees that **Client 2** is also connected, and so needs to get the **receiveSendEventArgs** reference to **Client 2** to forward the message.

However, the Server takes the reference of **receiveSendEventArgs** of **Client 2** and begins to prepare the buffer (SetBuffer) to send the message and I believe since the Socket is still in a "ReceiveSync" state for **Client 2**, it blows up with the following message:

"**An asynchronous socket operation is already in progress using this SocketAsyncEventArgs instance.**"

Is there a way to switch **Client 2** state on the Server from "ReceiveAsync"to "SendAsync" so that it doesn't error out when I try to SendData to **Client 2**? I know the **Completed** event is triggered when either Sending or Receiving operations complete, however, Simply Calling my **IO_Completed** method directly does not change the operation.

In a for loop setting up EventHandlers for Completed events for SocketAsyncEventArgs:
eventArgObjectForPool.Completed += new EventHandler(IO_Completed);

void IO_Completed(object sender, SocketAsyncEventArgs e){

```
        DataHoldingUserToken receiveSendToken = (DataHoldingUserToken)e.UserToken;
        //More business logic here ...
        // determine which type of operation just completed and call the associated handler
        switch (e.LastOperation)
        {
            case SocketAsyncOperation.Receive:
                if (Program.watchProgramFlow == true)   //for testing
                {
                    Program.testWriter.WriteLine("IO_Completed method in Receive, receiveSendToken id " + receiveSendToken.TokenId);
                }                    
                ProcessReceive(e);
                break;

            case SocketAsyncOperation.Send:
                if (Program.watchProgramFlow == true)   //for testing
                {
                    Program.testWriter.WriteLine("IO_Completed method in Send, id " + receiveSendToken.TokenId);
                }

                ProcessSend(e);
                break;

            default:
                //This exception will occur if you code the Completed event of some
                //operation to come to this method, by mistake.
                throw new ArgumentException("The last operation completed on the socket was not a receive or send");
        }
    }
```

private void StartReceive(SocketAsyncEventArgs receiveSendEventArgs)
        {

```
        DataHoldingUserToken receiveSendToken = (DataHoldingUserToken)receiveSendEventArgs.UserToken;

        if (Program.watchProgramFlow == true)   //for testing
        {                
            Program.testWriter.WriteLine("StartReceive(), receiveSendToken id " + receiveSendToken.TokenId);
        }

        switch (receiveSendToken.clientInfo.currentState)
        {
            case MyClient.ClientState.Connecting://This occurs when we get client to connect for first time. However, it will automatically disconnect

                receiveSendToken.theMediator.HandleData(receiveSendToken.theDataHolder);

                // Create a new DataHolder for next message.
                receiveSendToken.CreateNewDataHolder();

                //Reset the variables in the UserToken, to be ready for the
                //next message that will be received on the socket in this
                //SAEA object.
                receiveSendToken.Reset(true);

                receiveSendToken.theMediator.PrepareOutgoingData();
                StartSend(receiveSendToken.theMediator.GiveBack());

                //******************************************************************
                break;

            default:
                //Set the buffer for the receive operation.
                receiveSendEventArgs.SetBuffer(receiveSendToken.bufferOffsetReceive, this.socketListenerSettings.BufferSize);                    

                // Post async receive operation on the socket.
                bool willRaiseEvent = receiveSendEventArgs.AcceptSocket.ReceiveAsync(receiveSendEventArgs);

                //Socket.ReceiveAsync returns true if the I/O operation is pending. The 
                //SocketAsyncEventArgs.Completed event on the e parameter will be raised 
                //upon completion of the operation. So, true will cause the IO_Completed
                //method to be called when the receive operation completes. 
                //That's because of the event handler we created when building
                //the pool of SocketAsyncEventArgs objects that perform receive/send.
                //It was the line that said
                //eventArgObjectForPool.Completed += new EventHandler<SocketAsyncEventArgs>(IO_Completed);

                //Socket.ReceiveAsync returns false if I/O operation completed synchronously. 
                //In that case, the SocketAsyncEventArgs.Completed event on the e parameter 

                if (!willRaiseEvent)
                {
                    if (Program.watchProgramFlow == true)   //for testing
                    {
                        Program.testWriter.WriteLine("StartReceive in if (!willRaiseEvent), receiveSendToken id " + receiveSendToken.TokenId);
                    }

                    ProcessReceive(receiveSendEventArgs);
                }
                break;
        }
    }
```

private void StartSend(SocketAsyncEventArgs receiveSendEventArgs)
        {
            DataHoldingUserToken receiveSendToken = (DataHoldingUserToken)receiveSendEventArgs.UserToken;

```
        if (Program.watchProgramFlow == true)   //for testing
        {
            Program.testWriter.WriteLine("StartSend, id " + receiveSendToken.TokenId);
        }
        if (Program.watchThreads == true)   //for testing
        {
            DealWithThreadsForTesting("StartSend()", receiveSendToken);
        }

        if (receiveSendToken.sendBytesRemainingCount <= this.socketListenerSettings.BufferSize)
        {
            Program.testWriter.WriteLine("blocking:?(" + receiveSendEventArgs.AcceptSocket.Blocking + ")");
            receiveSendEventArgs.SetBuffer(receiveSendToken.bufferOffsetSend, receiveSendToken.sendBytesRemainingCount);
            //Copy the bytes to the buffer associated with this SAEA object.
            Buffer.BlockCopy(receiveSendToken.dataToSend, receiveSendToken.bytesSentAlreadyCount, receiveSendEventArgs.Buffer, receiveSendToken.bufferOffsetSend, receiveSendToken.sendBytesRemainingCount);
        }
        else
        {
            //We cannot try to set the buffer any larger than its size.
            //So since receiveSendToken.sendBytesRemainingCount > BufferSize, we just
            //set it to the maximum size, to send the most data possible.
            receiveSendEventArgs.SetBuffer(receiveSendToken.bufferOffsetSend, this.socketListenerSettings.BufferSize);
            //Copy the bytes to the buffer associated with this SAEA object.
            Buffer.BlockCopy(receiveSendToken.dataToSend, receiveSendToken.bytesSentAlreadyCount, receiveSendEventArgs.Buffer, receiveSendToken.bufferOffsetSend, this.socketListenerSettings.BufferSize);

            //We'll change the value of sendUserToken.sendBytesRemainingCount
            //in the ProcessSend method.
        }

        //post asynchronous send operation
        bool willRaiseEvent = receiveSendEventArgs.AcceptSocket.SendAsync(receiveSendEventArgs);

        if (!willRaiseEvent)
        {
            if (Program.watchProgramFlow == true)   //for testing
            {
                Program.testWriter.WriteLine("StartSend in if (!willRaiseEvent), receiveSendToken id " + receiveSendToken.TokenId);
            }

            ProcessSend(receiveSendEventArgs);
        }            
    }
```

Comment: Could you format  your question a little better and possibly provide some sample code and any errors/logs your getting?

Comment: The formatting update you did is nice but it is not nearly as important as adding a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This wasn't what I was wanting to do, but I was able to call the following:

receiveSendEventArgs.AcceptSocket.Write(strMyBuffer);

This allowed for me to write to the same socket and I did not have any errors. I was wanting to stick with The Async Commands but succumbed to a Sync write and it did not effect my server. Perhaps there are other solutions.

Comment: Probably you don't need async IO anyway so this solution is probably fine. In any case SAEA is an obsolete API. Use sockets with await. If all you want to do is forward data then all you need is two NetworkStreams and a single call to CopyTo(Async).